# Where can I find the definitive list of core blocks in html form

Tags: core, full-site-editing

I have been to [GitHub](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/tree/trunk/packages/block-library/src), but the documentation there is not what I'm looking for. I'm looking more this:

```
<!-- wp:post-featured-image /-->
<!-- wp:post-title /-->
<!-- wp:spacer {"height":40} -->
<!-- wp:post-content /-->
<!-- wp:spacer /-->
<!-- wp:group /-->
<!-- wp:template-part {"slug":"footer"} /-->
```

or is it just a matter of deduction: the name of the element concatenated with the wp comment structure:

`<!-- wp:` plus `post-title` plus optional attributes `{tag: something}` plus `/-->`

I've searched and can't find it if it exists.

Answer (score 4):

There's no definitive list that I'm aware of. If you want to get the markup for a block the only reliable way to do that is to insert it into the editor and then copy the result to the clipboard.

You cannot assume that all blocks are "`<!-- wp:` plus `post-title` plus optional attributes `{tag: something}` plus `/-->`", as many blocks also include HTML that they depend on. For example, the image block looks like this:

```
<!-- wp:image {"id":1934,"sizeSlug":"full","linkDestination":"none"} -->
<figure class="wp-block-image size-full"><img src="https://example.test/wp-content/uploads/2023/01/image-1.jpg" alt="" class="wp-image-1934"/></figure>
<!-- /wp:image -->
```

Just using the `<!--` part would not be sufficient.